# In pytest, how to skip all tests that use specified fixture?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

Suppose I have a fixture `fixture1` and I want to be able to skip all tests that use this fixture from pytest commandline.
I found answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179026/how-to-skip-a-pytest-using-an-external-fixture) quetion, but I decided to do it different way. 
I am marking all tests that uses `fixture1` with `using_fixture1` marker by defining following in my `conftest.py`

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    for item in items:
        try:
            fixtures=item.fixturenames
            if 'fixture1' in fixtures:
                item.add_marker(pytest.mark.using_fixture1)
        except:
            pass
```

And then, when running pytest I use: `py.test tests -m "not using_fixture1"`.

So the real question should be: Are there any better ways to do it and are there any drawbacks of my solution?

Comment: If it does what you need, that's the important thing, isn't it? :)

Comment: You can add `parser.parameter` at hook `pytest_addoption`. Then check this parameter by using `request.config.getoption` method and if so, call for `raise pytest.skip('skip me by cmdline opt')`.