# Pytest not able to skip testcase in a class via marker skipif

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I am using pytest framework and want to skip testcase based on some condition. Below code is not skipping the test case.

```
import pytest
class TEST:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
    def func_fixture(self):
        return "fail"

    @pytest.mark.skipif("self.func_fixture=='fail'")
    def test_setting_value(self):
        print("Hello I am in testcase")
```

When running, it is saying 0 testcases executed.

This `func_fixture` is very crucial for the testsuite. It performs many pre-requisites before starting the test.

If I remove class, and add rest of the functions with same syntax (after removing self), it works. Not sure why it is failing in class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

you can skip on condition inside the test itself; skip to **Suggestion** at the end of the answer. With your example code, skipping tests via `skipIf` markers is not possible.

---

First of all, let me clear the following: if you define an autouse fixture `foo` that returns a value, it does not mean the test class will automatically become an attribute `foo`.

```
class TestCls:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def fix(self):
        return 'foo'

    def test_fix(self):
        assert self.fix == 'foo'
```

Running this test will fail:

```
    def test_fix(self):
>       assert self.fix == 'foo'
E       AssertionError: assert <bound method TestCls.fix of <test_bacon.TestCls object at 0x105670cf8>> == 'foo'
E        +  where <bound method TestCls.fix of <test_bacon.TestCls object at 0x105670cf8>> = <test_bacon.TestCls object at 0x105670cf8>.fix
```

That's because that's not how fixtures work. If a fixture is returning something, you can access its return value if you add a parameter named same as the fixture, in the test function. This is a problem with classes because you can't pass fixtures as parameters to test class methods; overall, the support of test **classes** in `pytest` is limited. Not sure why you need classes at all; you can perfectly share the state between multiple test functions using fixtures alone. The whole intention of `pytest` is to make test classes obsolete, where every test method can be reworked to a test function.

If you need to share a value between tests in a class, you need to assign it to some attribute of the test class instance in the fixture. The example below will pass:

```
class TestCls:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def fix(self):
        self._fix = 'foo'

    def test_fix(self):
        assert self._fix == 'foo'
```

Thus, fixtures that actually **return** something are useless in test classes, because there's no way to pass fixtures as arguments in test class methods.

> Not sure why it is failing in class

That's because the markers are evaluated on tests collection to filter out tests that should be executed, and fixtures are executed only **after** the tests are collected and ready to run. This means what you want is not possible. You will not be able to pass any fixture result to `skipif` marker as no fixture is evaluated yet. Check the execution order:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def myfixture():
    print('myfixture called')


class TestCls:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def myclassfixture(self):
        print('TestCls.myclassfixture called')

    @pytest.mark.skipif('print(os.linesep, "TestCls.test_spam skipif called")', reason='something')
    def test_spam(self):
        print('TestCls.test_spam called')
```

Output:

```
TestCls.test_spam skipif called
myfixture called
TestCls.myclassfixture called
TestCls.test_spam called
```

Also note that the test class instance is not available in `skipif`, only what's defined on module level (classes, functions and global variables):

```
class Tests:

    @pytest.mark.skipif('print(os.linesep, "globals:", globals().keys(), os.linesep, "locals:", locals().keys())', reason='something')
    def test_spam(self):
        pass
```

Output:

```
test_spam.py::TestCls::test_spam
 globals: dict_keys(['os', 'sys', 'platform', 'config', '__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__file__', '__cached__', '__builtins__', '@py_builtins', '@pytest_ar', 'pytest', 'myfixture', 'TestCls'])
 locals: dict_keys(['os', 'sys', 'platform', 'config', '__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__file__', '__cached__', '__builtins__', '@py_builtins', '@pytest_ar', 'pytest', 'myfixture', 'TestCls'])
```

#### Suggestion

Besides the `skip`/`skipIf` markers, you can skip the test explicitly inside the test itself:

```
class TestCls:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def myfixture(self):
        self.status = 'fail'

    def test_eggs(self):
        if self.status == 'fail':
            pytest.skip('self.status is set to "fail"')
        assert False
```

If run, the test is skipped:

```
test_eggs.py::TestCls::test_eggs SKIPPED
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. If I want to update the value of status in any of the testcases to 'pass' , how can I do that ?

Comment: In one of testcases, i'm updating the value as if some_condition then self.status='pass' ,
But when i check in next test case as if self.status == 'pass', it still has 'fail'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62857682/how-to-skip-tests-based-on-condition-in-pytest?noredirect=1#comment111156247_62857682

Answer (score 2):

First, according to [Conventions for Python test discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery), the class name should starts with `Test`:

> From those files, collect test items:
>
> - `test_` prefixed test functions or
>     methods outside of class
> - test_ prefixed test functions or methods inside **`Test` prefixed test classes (without an __init__ method)**

```
class Test...:
```

---

Second, `func_fixture` in `@pytest.mark.skipif("func_fixture=='fail'")` is a function, not a return value of the function call. (I don't know how to use fixture value in`pytest.mark.skipif(..)`; See [this answer to see how to use fixture in expression for skipif](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28198398/2225682)).

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def func_fixture():
    return 'fail'


skip_by_fixture = pytest.mark.skipif("func_fixture() == 'fail'")

class TestSetting:
    @skip_by_fixture
    def test_setting_value(self):
        print("Hello I am in testcase")
```

Comment: You have moved fixture `func_fixture` out of class. What if I want to put this fixture inside class

Comment: Your code is working but I want the fixture func_fixture inside class.

Comment: @Nitesh, Sorry, I don't know how inject the fixture value into the expression for skipif / using instance method as a fixture.

Comment: @Nitesh, How about this: https://pastebin.com/Hw2C1kKa (`func_fixture` is not a fixture, just a static method)

Comment: now func_fixture is not a fixture. I am having actions that I am performing in a fixture. The idea is that if preconditions are not satisfied I don't want to execute testcase

Comment: @Nitesh, Even though it's not a fixture: It does what you want: Skip the test case if condition is not satisfied ;)  Change the `func_fixture` to return `'success'` and try `pytest`.

Comment: @falsetru : How can I do it, if have to update 'fail' to 'pass' on certain criteria. And later skip rest of the test cases if it's 'pass'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62857682/how-to-skip-tests-based-on-condition-in-pytest?noredirect=1#comment111156247_62857682

Answer (score 1):

Pytest provides a feature to manage dependencies of tests. You can create a separate test and set dependency on successive tests. You need to install pytest-dependency.

`pip install pytest-dependency`

Example:

```
class TestExample(object):

    @pytest.mark.dependency()
    def test_func(self):
        assert False

    @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["TestExample::test_func"])
    def test_setting_value(self):
        print("Hello I am in testcase")
```

Comment: Your answer is not very clear. Can you explain it more

Comment: You can assert your condition which you've used in your fixture in a seperate test, say test_func(in above example). If the `test_func` passes, only then `test_setting_value` will be executed, else that test will be skipped, as we have set dependency of test_func on this test.

Comment: `test_func` is actually a fixture which perform certain steps before a test case start. can @pytest.mark.dependency be merged with fixtures too ?

Comment: It only allows to mark some tests as dependent from other tests. These tests will then be skipped if any of the dependencies did fail or has been skipped. But in your case, you can replace your fixture with a test which will be executed first and set dependency on other tests. [https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#basic-usage]

Answer (score 1):

First, class name with just `TEST` will not work.

Second, fixture sometimes is a pain ..., I would just use a plain method to check and return condition to skip(fail) or not.

```
import pytest
import unittest


class TestSkipWithoutFixture(unittest.TestCase):

    def fixture_sometimes_suck():
        return "fail"

    @pytest.mark.skipif(fixture_sometimes_suck() == 'fail', reason='just skip')
    def test_setting_value(self):
        print("Hello I am in testcase")

    def test_to_pass(self):
        pass
```

test results `pytest -v tests/test_skip.py`

```
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.14, pytest-3.2.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /usr/bin/python2

collected 2 items                                                                                                                                 

tests/test_skip.py::TestSkipWithoutFixture::test_setting_value SKIPPED
tests/test_skip.py::TestSkipWithoutFixture::test_to_pass PASSED
```

Comment: If there's a condition check inside 'test_setting_value' , if a == 1, then rest of the testcases should be skipped. Is that possible ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62847026/how-can-we-halt-stop-fail-test-cases-if-a-condition-fails-in-another-test-case?noredirect=1#comment111137349_62847026

Comment: @StackGuru, fasetru's answer is closed related to your question, there is no order which test run first in a TestClass, so the condition has to be outside of a test class, a fixture if preferred if the same condition for all tests inside a class, but still, the skipif fixture has to be on top of each test func

Comment: how can i update "fail" to "pass" on certain criteria in one of the testcases. Later add marker skipif accordingly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62857682/how-to-skip-tests-based-on-condition-in-pytest?noredirect=1#comment111156247_62857682