# How to skip tests based on condition in pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-markers

Below is the snippet of `conftest.py`, which accepts command line arguments.

**conftest.py**

```
import sys,json,pytest
import logging

def tear_down():
    logging.info(" tear-down after all tests")

def pytest_addoption(parser):

    parser.addoption("--a1", action="store", default="default_a1",
                     help="value of a1")

    parser.addoption("--b1", action="store", default="default_b1",
                     help="value of b1")


 @pytest.fixture(scope="class",autouse=True)
def set_up(request):
    logging.info("set-up before all tests")

    a1 = request.config.getoption("--a1")
    b1 = request.config.getoption("--b1")

    if request.cls.__name__ == 'Test1':
        return([a1,b1])

    request.addfinalizer(tear_down)
```

> Below snippet is of `test.py`
>
> Whenever the `counter value not equal to 1` i.e., `c1_1 != 1`
> `(test_2)` then it should skip all the following cases. Probably I can
> try checking this condition in each and every test-case and then
> `pytest.skip or assert False`. But this is not great idea.
>
> I tried marker `pytest.mark.skipif` , but within that marker `"can't access variable skip_all" (either "Test1.skip_all")` `I would like to skip tests based on certain condition.` If my below approach is not right, please help me
> with right approach to skip tests based on condition.

**test.py**

```
import os,sys
import pytest
from other import other_class

a1_1 = b1_1 = c1_1 = ""

class Test1:
   skip_all = False

    def test_1(self,set_up):
        try:
            global a1_1,b1_1
            a1_1 = set_up[0]
            b1_1 = set_up[1]
        except Exception as err:
            logging.error(err)
            Test1.skip_all = True
            assert False, err
            
    @pytest.mark.skipif(skip_all == True, reason="Invalid")
    def test_2(self):
        global c1_1
        c1_1 = obj.func1(a1_1,b1_1)
        if c1_1 != 1:      #rest all test-cases shouldn't execute
           logging.error("Invalid")
           Test1.skip_all = True
           
        d1_1 = obj.func2(a1_1, c1_1)
        if d1_1 == 0:
           assert False, "zero"
        
    @pytest.mark.skipif(skip_all == True, reason="Zero")
    def test_3(self):
        d1_1 = obj.func2(b1_1, c1_1)
        if d1_1 == 0:
           assert False, "zero"

    @pytest.mark.skipif(skip_all == True, reason="Zero")
    def test_4(self):
       d1_1 = obj.func2(a1_1, c1_1)
       if d1_1 == 0:
          assert False, "zero"

obj = other_class()
```

Am I missing anything ? or anything to do with fixtures ?
Is this possible ? Can anyone please let me know how to do that ?

In below example, how can we use external variable that's accessible in `marker:skipif` , instead of `'sys.platform'`

```
import sys
import pytest

@pytest.mark.skipif(sys.platform != 'darwin', reason="Mac tests")
def test_mac():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.skipif(sys.platform != 'linux', reason="Linux tests")
def test_linux():
    assert True 

@pytest.mark.skipif(sys.platform != 'win32', reason="Windows tests")
def test_windows():
    assert True 

@pytest.mark.skip(reason="To show we can skip tests without any condition.")
def test_any():
    assert True
```

Comment: you'd probably do best to decide to skip inside your fixture, by raising `pytest.skip` based on the arguments (then you don't need anything special in your tests) - a pytest maintainer

Comment: @Anthony Sottoke : Thank you. Didn't get that, just started learning pytest. Can you please help me ?

Comment: @Anthony Sottile : us this possible ?

Comment: If you want tests depend on each other, check out the [`pytest-dependency`](https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) plugin. Instead of `skipif`, use the `@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=['Test1::test_1'])` marker etc. See esp. [Using test classes](https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-test-classes) for an example matching your case.

Comment: @hoefling Thank you. For test dependency it works. How based on certain variable value ? In above case, variable 'skip_all' , how can it be done ?

Comment: @hoefling 'skip_all' variable varies dynamically in one of the test-cases.

Comment: @hoefling could able to it based on test function. but how about based on variable that changes dynamically ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62902460/how-can-i-use-test-data-external-variable-in-pytest-dependency

Answer (score 1):

first, a function `skip_test()`

```
def skip_test():
    return 1

# attention the quote and func call
skipmeif = pytest.mark.skipif("skip_test() == 1")
```

to skipif a function `@skipmeif test_func1`, to skipif a class do `@skipmeif class TestSth`

second, for the skip condition in your case, here is a possible solution but not sure fit your purpose

```
def skip_test():
    obj = SomeClass()
    c1 = obj.sth()
    return c1
```

Comment: `func` is incorrect syntax for python, use `def` to declare a function or method.