# How to use a variable from setup fixture outside fixture

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, fixtures, parameterization

I want to use the product variable present inside `setupone` fixture outside it. I want to use it in test_title.py in `skipif` marker for conditional skipping (run the test case if product name satisfies).
**conftest.py**

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser_name", action="store", default="chrome")
    parser.addoption("--env", action="store", default="Production")
    parser.addoption("--product_name", nargs = '*', type = str, action ="store", default="chitale")

products_list = getProductList()

@pytest.fixture(scope='class', params = products_list)
def setupone(request):
    browser = request.config.getoption("browser_name")
    env_name = request.config.getoption("env")
    product = request.param
```

(getProductList() returns ["product1", "product2", "product3"] which is stored in product_list)

**BaseOne.py**

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setupone")
class BaseOne:
    pass
```

**test_title.py**

```
from conftest import prod

class TestStoreTitle(BaseOne):

    @pytest.mark.skipif(prod not in ["product1", "product2", "product3"], reason="test case doesn't apply for desired product")
    def test_Store_Title(self):
        pass
```

I want to use the product from `setupone` outside the function like:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser_name", action="store", default="chrome")
    parser.addoption("--env", action="store", default="Production")
    parser.addoption("--product_name", nargs = '*', type = str, action ="store", default="chitale")

products_list = getProductList()

@pytest.fixture(scope='class', params = products_list)
def setupone(request):
    browser = request.config.getoption("browser_name")
    env_name = request.config.getoption("env")
    product = request.param

prod = product
```

Comment: 1. You haven't used `product` outside, what you used was `products`. 2. Why do you need to use it outside? Why not just return it from `setupone` and then define a new fixture that will accept `setupone`?

Comment: I want to use product out of fixture

Comment: I'm not asking **what** you want. I'm asking **why** (the purpose). Can you paste the code where you target to use `product`? I am asking as possibly you don't need it and you can just create another fixture which will process products from `setupone`. Just to avoid [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I've edited the description, plz check, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to just access the product from its fixture `setupone`.

- Return the value of product from the fixture `setupone`
- Define an autouse-fixture that will automatically process the skipping mark for products via [get_closest_marker()](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.nodes.Node.get_closest_marker), which below would be `skip_product_not_in_list`
- Pass the list of wanted products to the mark `skip_product_not_in_list`
- If the current product from `setupone` is not in the wanted list, skip it via [pytest.skip()](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/skipping.html#skipping-test-functions)

```
import pytest

products_list = ["product1", "product2", "product3"]


@pytest.fixture(scope='class', params=products_list)
def setupone(request):
    product = request.param
    return product


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def skip_non_applicable_products(request, setupone):
    if product_marker := request.node.get_closest_marker("skip_product_not_in_list"):
        if setupone not in product_marker.args[0]:
            # Option 1
            # pytest.skip(product_marker.kwargs.get('reason'))
            # Option 2
            pytest.skip(f"{product_marker.kwargs.get('reason') or 'Skipped'} {setupone}")


def test_Store_Title_all_products(setupone):
    print("test_Store_Title_all_products:", setupone)


@pytest.mark.skip_product_not_in_list(["product1", "product3"], reason="test case doesn't apply for desired product")
def test_Store_Title_skip_products(setupone):
    print("test_Store_Title_skip_products:", setupone)
```

**Output**

```
$ pytest -rPS test_src.py
============================================== PASSES ===============================================
______________________________ test_Store_Title_all_products[product1] ______________________________
--------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------
test_Store_Title_all_products: product1
_____________________________ test_Store_Title_skip_products[product1] ______________________________
--------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------
test_Store_Title_skip_products: product1
______________________________ test_Store_Title_all_products[product2] ______________________________
--------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------
test_Store_Title_all_products: product2
______________________________ test_Store_Title_all_products[product3] ______________________________
--------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------
test_Store_Title_all_products: product3
_____________________________ test_Store_Title_skip_products[product3] ______________________________
--------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------
test_Store_Title_skip_products: product3
====================================== short test summary info ======================================
SKIPPED [1] test_src.py:19: test case doesn't apply for desired product product2
============================== 5 passed, 1 skipped, 1 warning in 0.08s ==============================
```

- For `test_Store_Title_all_products`, it tested all products. For `test_Store_Title_skip_products` in where we defined a custom list, we can see that it skipped the `"product2"` because it wasn't in the list.

Related question:

- [How to skip a pytest using an external fixture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179026/how-to-skip-a-pytest-using-an-external-fixture)

Comment: Glad it helped :) If its all the answer you need, you might want to accept it as the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers